# Rails and Arel's where function: Can I call where on objects instead of making a call to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

Consider the following:

- `budget` has many `object`s in its `another_collection`.
- `obj` has many objects of the same type as `object` in its `another_collection`.
- `budget` and `some_collection` are already declared before the following loop
  they've been previous saved in the database and have primary keys set.
- `some_collection` is a collections of `obj`s.

-

```
some_collection.each do |obj|
  another_obj = obj.another_collection.build
  budget.another_collection << another_obj
end

budget.another_collection.collect {|another_obj| another_obj.another_obj_id}
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
some_obj_with_pk_1 = some_collection.where(obj_id: obj.id)
some_obj_with_pl_1.id
=> 1
budget.another_collection.where(another_obj_id: some_obj_with_pk_1.id)
=> []
```

This shouldn't happen. What is happening is that rails queries the database for any items in `another_collection` with another_obj_id = 1. Since this collection hasn't been saved to the database yet, none of these items are showing up in the results.

Is there a function or something I can pass to Arel's `where` method that says to use local results **only**? I know I can just iterate over the items and find it but it would be great if I didn't have to do that and just use a method that does this already.

Comment: No you can't, and yes this is expected behavior. You are constructing a query which is ran against the database. Why would it do anything else besides querying the database and returning results from there?

Comment: I never said this was a bug and my assumption here is that it **is** expected behavior. I was asking if Arel supported what I was doing and if not, is there a method in the rails framework to do what I'm asking.

Comment: You kind of answered your question earlier yourself. If you want to find stuff from the unsaved collection, you need to iterate and filter that collection based on your conditions. You cannot query it with Arel.

Comment: Ok, well my question was if I could use Arel to iterate over unsaved objects or if there was another method in the rails framework that did this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use [Enumeable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) which takes a block and returns only the elements that the block returns `true` for. You'd want to make sure that you had ActiveRecord retrieve the result set first (by calling `to_a` on your query).

```
records = Model.where(some_attribute: value).to_a
filtered_records = records.select { |record| record.something? }
```

Depending on your result set and your needs, it is possible that a second database query would be faster, as your SQL store is better suited to do these comparisons than Ruby. But if your records have yet to be saved, you would need to do something like the above, since the records aren't persisted yet